# Assign Values to Variable in Java

Tags: java, memory, memory-management

I am trying to understand how this works

```
public class LinkedListMultiset<T> extends Multiset<T> {
private Node<T> head;

public LinkedListMultiset() {
    this.head = null;
} // end of LinkedListMultiset()


public void add(T item) {
    Node<T> node = new Node(item);

    if (head == null) {
        head = node;
    } else {
        Node<T> currentNode = head;
        while (currentNode.getNext() != null) {
            //-----------------------------------
            currentNode = currentNode.getNext();
            //-----------------------------------

        }
        currentNode.setNext(node);
    }
}

}
```

At the point where currentNode is assigned to the next node in the current node shouldnt that node be a completely new node in itself. but for some reason it is attach to the list?

Comment: In `shouldnt that node be a completely new node in itself. but for some reason it is attach to the list` it's not clear what you're asking. The new item is a new node as done here - `Node<T> node = new Node(item);`and it's attached to the tail so that it could be reached when traversing the list.

Answer (score 0):

This code tries to traverse the list until the last node. When `currentNode.getNext() == null` we have reached the last node. So `currentNode.setNext(node);` is called.